# Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP displayed in view as {".sv":"timestamp"} with .push()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have this following function in my controller:

```
  $scope.add = function(newItem){
    if (!(newItem.title && newItem.text)) return;
    var sanitized = {
      title: newItem.title,
      text: newItem.text,
      date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    };
    // $rootScope.currentUser is here bound with $firebaseObject(ref).$bindTo($rootScope, 'currentUser').
    $rootScope.currentUser.list.push(sanitized);
    // .list is an array: []. 
  };
```

And I utilise this in my view like follows:

```
    <form name="newUp">
        <input ng-model="newItem.title">
        <textarea ng-model="newItem.text"></textarea>
        <button ng-click="add(newItem)">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <div ng-repeat="item in currentUser.list | orderBy:'-date'">
     <p>
      <span><a href="">{{item.title}}</a> <small>  -&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.date | date:'d MMM yy'}}</small></span><br>
      <span ng-if="item.text"><small>{{item.text}}</small></span>
     </p>
    </div>
```

However after the submit button is clicked, and the item is saved to the firebase database, it displays on screen as:

`{".sv":"timestamp"}`

After I refresh the page entirely, it shows the item(s) with the correct timestamp(s). Is there a way to avoid this? Can I avoid using $firebaseArray to fix this?

I am using bower which has pulled down the following versions:

- AngularFire 1.1.2
- Firebase v2.2.7
- AngularJS v1.4.1

Comment: Which version of the Firebase client library / Angular library, are you using?

Comment: I've added the versions to the question, good point. Everything is on latest except angular (bower won't pull down 1.4.2 for some reason), should that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a [quick glance](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/aqpyycoL/) there is a [bug](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/636) in work of `$firebaseObject`. It's obvious that it doesn't treat properly value of a special object `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` which tells server to put the timestamp *on server-side*. However this is not the case when adding same object in to `$firebaseArray` with a synchronized method `$add`.

Perhaps I am missing some kind of `flush` method for `$firebaseObject` but I can't find it.

In any case you should use `$firebaseArray` because your data is of type `Array`. And don't forget to use `$add`, `$save` and `$remove` as per [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-arrays)

Comment: Thank you. This answers the question because it a) clarifies I wasn't doing anything wrong, & b) I was trying to avoid constructing specific ref's on the fly all the time, but I'm deciding this is a bad pattern, so following the docs which were linked is then the natural thing to do.